# Set MessageBox.Show() owner to main form from a user control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, messagebox

I'm using a customized `Messagebox` on a `User Control` in my Winform. The `Owner` in its `Show()` method is of type `Iwin32Window` and so if I use `this` for it, it does not work. 
How can I set this owner to my program's main form without creating a new instance of it?

**Update**:
Definition of the MessageBox class I'm using.

```
public static class MetroMessageBox
{
    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, string message);
    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, string message, string title);
    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, string message, string title, MessageBoxButtons buttons);
    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, string message, string title, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon);
    public static DialogResult Show(IWin32Window owner, string message, string title, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultbutton);
}
```

Comment: Define "does not work".  `this` should be fine.

Comment: "does not work" means nothing happens. Nothing is displayed.

Comment: @DonBoitnott I updated the post with the definition of this MessageBox I'm using. It is not the normal MessageBox.

Comment: We're not seeing enough of your program.  The posted code produces an error: `MetroMessageBox.Show(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window, string) must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial`

Comment: @LarsTech It's inside a .dll. I cannot see the code.